# Replace matches according to the pattern that was matched

Tags: regex, r, string, substitution

Given a set of regular expressions, is there a simple way to match multiple patterns, and replace the matched text according to the pattern that was matched?

For example, for the following data `x`, each element begins with either a number or a letter, and ends with either a number or a letter. Let's call these patterns `num_num` (for begins with number, ends with number), `num_let` (begins with number, ends with letter), `let_num`, and `let_let`.

```
x <- c('123abc', '78fdsaq', 'aq12111', '1p33', '123', 'pzv')
type <- list(
  num_let='^\\d.*[[:alpha:]]$',
  num_num='^\\d(.*\\d)?$',
  let_num='^[[:alpha:]].*\\d$',
  let_let='^[[:alpha:]](.*[[:alpha:]])$'
)
```

To replace each string with the name of the pattern it follows, we could do:

```
m <- lapply(type, grep, x)
rep(names(type), sapply(m, length))[order(unlist(m))]
## [1] "num_let" "num_let" "let_num" "num_num" "num_num" "let_let"
```

Is there a more efficient approach?

---

#### `gsubfn`?

I know that with `gsubfn` we can simultaneously replace different matches, e.g.:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('.*', list('1p33'='foo', '123abc'='bar'), x)
## [1] "bar"     "78fdsaq" "aq12111" "foo"     "123"     "pzv"
```

but I'm not sure whether the replacements can be made dependent on the *pattern that was matched* rather than on the match itself.

---

#### `stringr`?

`str_replace_all` doesn't play nicely with this example, since matches are replaced for patterns iteratively, and we end up with everything being overwritten with `let_let`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, setNames(names(type), unlist(type)))
## [1] "let_let" "let_let" "let_let" "let_let" "let_let" "let_let"
```

Reordering `type` so the pattern corresponding to `let_let` appears first solves the problem, but needing to do this makes me nervous.

```
type2 <- rev(type)
str_replace_all(x, setNames(names(type2), unlist(type2)))
## [1] "num_let" "num_let" "let_num" "num_num" "num_num" "let_let"
```

Comment: What is the motivation behind the question? Are you looking for a computationally efficient method, a method which relies on a single function call or something else?

Comment: @NGaffney - For my application, computational efficiency doesn't matter so much - I won't be scaling this problem up much, and only need to perform the operation a couple of times. I posted the question because I've run into this a couple of times in the past, and suspected that there'd be a way to solve the problem (particularly with, e.g., `gsubfn`, which is still a bit of a mystery to me). I was mainly just interested in seeing alternative approaches to the problem, and building my string manipulation repertoire. I'd like to see an approach that relies on a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### stringr

We can use `str_replace_all` if we alter the replacements so they are no longer matched by any of the regular expressions and then add an additional replacement to return them to their original form. For example

```
library(stringr)
type2 <- setNames(c(str_replace(names(type), "(.*)", "__\\1__"), "\\1"), 
                  c(unlist(type), "^__(.*)__$"))
str_replace_all(x, type2)
## [1] "num_let" "num_let" "let_num" "num_num" "num_num" "let_let"
```

---

#### grepl and tidyr

Another approach is match first and then replace, one way to do this is to use `grepl` and `tidyr`

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

out <- data.frame(t(1*aaply(type, 1, grepl, x)))

out[out == 0] <- NA
out <- out %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  gather(name,value, -id, na.rm = T) %>%
  select(name)
as.character(out[,1])
## [1] "num_let" "num_let" "num_num" "num_num" "let_num" "let_let"
```

While this approach doesn't look as efficient it makes it easy to find rows where there are more or less than one match.

---

From what I understand substitution matching is implemented in pcre2 and I believe allows this type of problem to be solved directly in the regex. Unfortunately it seems that no one has built a pcre2 package for R yet.

Comment: I like the replacement you tacked onto the end of `type2` - very clever.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one of these.

```
# base R method
mm2 <- character(length(x))
for( n in 1:length(type))  mm2 <- replace(mm2, grep(type[n],x), names(type)[n]) 

# purrr 0.2.0 method
library(purrr)
mm3 <- map(grep, .x=type, x = x) %>% (function(z) replace(x, flatten_int(z), rep(names(type), lengths(z))))
```

The base R method is somewhat faster than the posted code for both small and larger data sets.  The `purrr` method is slower than the posted code for small data sets but about the same as the base R method for larger data sets.